# Azure SQL Can't Connect to DB through SSMS Though User Can Log Into Different DB on The Same Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I have a SQL Server on Azure with two databases which I can see just fine with the admin account

[image: Two Databases on SQL Server]

Now using a regular user account I need to specify the DB i want to connect on the configuration settings of SSMS. As you can see I can connect just fine to sqldb01

[image: Single DB on SQL Server]

These are the current permissions for the user on the db is able to see sqldb01
[image]

But when I try to connect to the sqldb01Review I get a 'login failed for user'.
[image]

User has connect grant on the DB
[image]

The database sqldb01Review is a restored DB. I have addeddataread and data writer as roles and as you can see I even added db_owner for testing purposes but still can't see it on SSMS

[image: User Permissions on Restored DB]

What am I missing?